# Is there a decent video converter / cropper for linux?

Tags: linux, video-conversion

I have an x264/mkv file and I need to cut out a small portion of the clip. Nothing I tried seems to do the job.

I tried Avidemux but seeking doesn't work even if I rebuild the index. (I've tried this a few weeks ago with an xvid/avi file and the result was always out of sync no matter what settings I use).
I tried converting it to avi or mpg using mencoder and ffmpeg and the resulting video doesn't play in any player.
I tried transcoding it using vlc but it says vlc could not open the encoder.
I tried kino but it was taking forever to import the clip.

I've wasted over 2 hours on such a trivial task and accomplished nothing. So can this even be done on linux or is my only option to install windows on vmware?

Comment: You may find one of the entries on [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/top5-linux-video-editing-system-software/) list of use.

Comment: Tried them all. Either they use too much RAM, or too slow, or the format isn't supported or the result is out of sync.

Installed windows and did the job in 5 minutes.